# Multiple results from index-match on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a spreadsheet at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mFOgFk5uRHyEB1cK_FIgwLmU6ac8etbWDpT_MDnKXI8/edit?usp=sharing in which I am trying to find the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th results from an index-match formula. I have tried using the small() function but it does not seem to work. If you look at Station 1... Cell F29 is grabbing the first result. Cell F28 should be grabbing the second result... but it does not work. Cell F27 should grab the 3rd (If there was a third) and cell F26 the forth result (If there was one.)

The formula I am currently using is...

```
=if(or(isna(index('SSI Tracker'!$A:$F,small(match(F25,'SSI Tracker'!$D:$D,0),2),2)),index('SSI Tracker'!$A:$F,small(match(F25,'SSI Tracker'!$D:$D,0),2),2)=""),"",concatenate(index('SSI Tracker'!$A:$F,small(match(F25,'SSI Tracker'!$D:$D,0),2),1)," / ",index('SSI Tracker'!$A:$F,small(match(F25,'SSI Tracker'!$D:$D,0),2),2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

F29:

```
=JOIN(" / ",query('SSI Tracker'!A:D,"select A, B where D = '"&$F$25&"' limit 1 offset 0",0))
```

And change offset parameter:

```
F28: ...offset 1...
F27: ...offset 2...
F26: ...offset 3...
```

Will bring #N/A if not found, so you may also use `iferror`

But in this case you need different formula for each cell. Some additional work will help:

1. In separate columns [H, I]: paste lookup valuses for offset [0,1,2,3] and condition [Station 01, Station 02...]
2. Edit formula in F29: `=Iferror(JOIN(" / ",query('SSI Tracker'!A:D,"select A, B where D = '"& I29 &"' limit 1 offset " & H29,0)),"Not found")`
3. Copy formulas

Comment: Works great - Thanks!  This is what I have now... `=iferror(JOIN(" / ",query('SSI Tracker'!$A:$D,"select A, B where D = '"&F25&"' limit 1 offset 0",0)))`